# best way to combine two sql tables with multiple conditions and one max condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I've two tables : Materials and inventory.

I want to get the list of all the materials with their latest stock if available, otherwise just zero.

TABLE - MATERIALS

```
id        | material    | 
==========================
1         |Lily - Blue    
2         |Lily - Orange    
3         |Lily - White
4         |Rose - Blue    
5         |Rose - Orange    
6         |Rose - White
```

TABLE - INVENTORY

```
id        | date      | material   | final_stock | entry_time           | 
=========================================================================
1         |2018-05-18 |Lily - Blue |  30         |  2018-05-18 09:06:48 |        
2         |2018-05-18 |Lily - white|  10         |  2018-05-18 10:32:27 |        
3         |2018-05-18 |Lily - Blue |  90         |  2018-05-18 15:30:31 |
```

my query :

```
select materials.material, max(inventory.final_stock) from materials left join 
inventory on materials.material = inventory.material
```

output

```
material    | max(inventory.final_stock)| 
========================================
Lily - Blue |90
```

output required >>

```
date       | material     | max(inventory.final_stock)| 
======================================================
2018-05-18 | Lily - Blue  |90
2018-05-18 | Lily - Orange|0
2018-05-18 | Lily - white |10
2018-05-18 | Rose - Blue  |0    
2018-05-18 | Rose - Orange|0    
2018-05-18 | Rose - white |0
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: thank you @Strawberry. ill make use of sqlfiddle next time

Comment: It's not too late to do it this time. In my experience, it immeasurably improves the quality of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select m.*,
       coalesce( (select i.final_stock
                  from inventory i
                  where i.material = m.material
                  order by i.entry_time desc
                  limit 1
                 ), 0) as final_stock
from materials m;
```

Note that one of the major reasons for having an `id` in a table is so it can be used for foreign key relationships.  Hence, `inventory` should have a `material_id` column, not a `material` column.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the `JOIN` with `subquery` :

```
select m.material, coalesce(i.final_stock, 0) as final_stock
from materials m 
left outer join (select material, max(final_stock) final_stock
                 from INVENTORY 
                 group by material  
                 ) i on i.material = m.material;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
with inv as
(
select  m.material
       ,i.date
       ,i.final_stock
       ,Max(i.Entry_time) over (Partition By i.material) maxLog
from materials m
left join inventory i on m.material = i.material 
)
Select date, material, final_stock
From inv where entry_time = maxLog
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a sub-query to populate the missing elements, then use conditionals to fill in the Null fields.  The below query matches the conditions asked for in your question.

Be aware in a 'live' system I would not just seek the max(final_stock) on any given date as the 'final_stock' item.  If the 'entry_time' is supposed to the the most recent entry for a given stock item I would re-work this query to use that as the latest 'inventory entry' to be referenced.  But to do so opens the issue of whether someone is allowed in your system to back-date inventory entries.

```
SELECT 
  ifnull(C.date,(SELECT max(date) FROM inventory)) AS date,
  C.material,
  ifnull(max(D.final_stock),0) AS final_stock 
FROM (
  SELECT
    max(B.date) AS date,
    A.material 
  FROM materials A LEFT JOIN inventory B ON A.material = B.material 
  GROUP BY A.material
  ) AS C LEFT JOIN inventory D ON C.material=D.material AND C.date = D.date 
  GROUP BY C.material,C.date
  ORDER BY C.material,C.date
```

results below

```
date        material        final_stock
2018-05-18  Lily - Blue     90
2018-05-18  Lily - Orange   0
2018-05-18  Lily - White    10
2018-05-18  Rose - Blue     0
2018-05-18  Rose - Orange   0
2018-05-18  Rose - White    0
```

If you are allowed to make use of the entry_time field then the query below is a better solution.  This query also no longer has to use aggregation in the outer query.  The result for your dataset is the same.

```
SELECT 
  ifnull(D.date,(SELECT max(date) FROM inventory)) AS date,
  C.material,
  ifnull(D.final_stock,0) AS final_stock 
FROM (
  SELECT
    max(B.entry_time) as entry_time,
    A.material 
  FROM materials A LEFT JOIN inventory B ON A.material = B.material 
  GROUP BY A.material
  ) AS C LEFT JOIN inventory D ON 
    C.material=D.material AND 
    C.entry_time = D.entry_time
    ORDER BY C.material
```

Comment: The basic rule is, if a non-aggregated column is included in the SELECT then it must also appear in the GROUP BY

Comment: @Strawberry as per your comment I have re-worked the query.